# How to display a list of authors in bootstrap grid?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Basically I am struggling to display the author list in a grid:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-4">
<?php 

wp_list_authors( array(
    'show_fullname' => 1,
    'optioncount'   => 1,
    'exclude' => 4,
    'orderby'       => 'post_count',
    'order'         => 'DESC',
    'number'        => 60
) ); ?>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Should I use the user table instead of is there a loop I can use against the author list?

Thank you

Comment: You're on the right track with using a loop. The problem you are running into is [`wp_list_authors`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_authors/) returns a list either comma separated or as `<li>` but you want to pass the data into a grid. Can you update your question with what the HTML markup that each author should be wrapped in for those of us who don't use Bootstrap?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not many ways to style the `wp_list_author` but you can use the `style => 'list'` argument to display authors in `<li>` and then style your `<ul>`as wanted.
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_authors/

```
    <div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-4">
    <ul class="d-flex">
<?php 

wp_list_authors( array(
    'exclude' => 4,
    'show_fullname' => 1,
    'optioncount'   => 1,
    'orderby'       => 'post_count',
    'order'         => 'DESC',
    'number'        => 60,
    'style'         => 'list',
) ); ?>

    </ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

For example adding the `d-flex`class to your `<ul>`

You could also use the `get_users`function.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_users/

I update my code below with this query you can have the bootstrap grid ;)

```
<?php 
$users    = get_users('');
$query    = get_users( [ 'role__in' => [ 'author', 'editor' ],
                        'number'=> 60,
    'exclude' => 4,
    'orderby'       => 'post_count',
    'order'         => 'DESC', ]);

?>
 <div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <?php
foreach($query as $q) { ?>


<div class="col-lg-4">
          <?php echo get_the_author_meta('display_name', $q->ID);?>
</div>

<?php } ?>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks thats certainly an interesting way, is it possible to loop it instead to a bootstrap column? The wordpress documentation  on this function isn't very clear

Comment: After further search, I updated my answer with a solution wich will allow you to loop the authors. If ok thanx to mark as solved

Comment: thank looks perfect but i am getting the wordpress white page of death when i add it to my custom author page:
<?php 
$users    = get_users('');
$query    = get_users( [ 'role__in' => [ 'author', 'editor' ],
                        'number'=> 60,
    'optioncount'   => 1,
    'exclude' => 4,
    'orderby'       => 'post_count',
    'order'         => 'DESC', ]);

?>
 <div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <?php
foreach($query as $q) { ?>


<div class="col-lg-4">
          <?php echo get_the_author_meta('display_name', $q->ID);?>
</div>

<?php } ?>
</div>
</div>

Comment: You should activate debug mode to get the corresponding error message.

Comment: [08-May-2020 11:53:34 UTC] PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/ 

I feel so out of my depth here and really appreciate any help

Comment: Is it in the same loop? You could try removing arguments from your query and test if the warning is still here. I tested on my WP dev blog without error but I don't have enough authors to test the limits, order... args you supplied. I will add the link for the `get_users`function in my answer.

Comment: Well the `optioncount` argument is not listed in wp user query. Try to remove it, I updated my code. Let me know if it was the error source.

Comment: thank you! it works on another site of mine just not this one so i've no idea what the issue it. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score -1):

It looks like this can be achieved easily using **Visual Composer plugin**.

**Take a look at this link with brief instructions.**

**https://wpexplorer-themes.com/total/docs/display-users/**

**Here's a link to the plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/visualcomposer/**

Comment: Thanks but I am not using that theme, I am coding my own and wish to do it without plugins

Comment: Can I see a link to the current page?